# String.split() by one of two patterns

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split

I want to split this string: 315-045/10-20 to this array: ["315","045","10","20"], meaning it should be split around every occurrence of '/' or '-'.
Is it possible to do it with one call to the split() function?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex which accepts both slashes and dashes.

```
String input = "315-045/10-20";
String[] output = input.split("[/-]");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could alternatively use a non-digit `split` pattern:

```
"315-045/10-20".split("\\D");
```

Comment: This would work in my case, but if I had some more none numeric elements in the string it wouldn't. Still it's a good answer so +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ...

```
split("[-/]")
```